# jQuery find image in div and save src as variable to use as css background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several divs on a page that have 1 randomly generated image in each div. I need to be able to find the image source value for each of those images and save them to a variable. I then need to assign those images as background css to other elements on the page. Example:

```
<div class="wrapper div1"><img src="/image1.png" /></div>
<div class="wrapper div2"><img src="/image2.png" /></div>
<div class="wrapper div3"><img src="/image3.png" /></div>

<div class="background div1"></div>
<div class="background div2"></div>
<div class="background div3"></div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    var div1Image = $('.wrapper.div1').find('img').attr('src');
    var div2Image = $('.wrapper.div2').find('img').attr('src');
    var div3Image = $('.wrapper.div3').find('img').attr('src');
    $('.background.div1').css('background-image', "url(' + div1Image + ') no-repeat");
    $('.background.div2').css('background-image', "url(' + div2Image + ') no-repeat");
    $('.background.div3').css('background-image', "url(' + div3Image + ') no-repeat");
});
```

This code does nothing though. Am I going about this all wrong? Any thoughts as to what I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: In fact, you have misquoted: `"url(' + div2Image + ') no-repeat"` should be: `"url(" + div2Image + ") no-repeat"` and you should set background, not background-image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The css-property `background-image` does not support `no-repeat`. Furhtermore your quotes are mismatching.

The following should work:

```
$(function() {
  var div1Image = $('.wrapper.div1').find('img').attr('src');
  var div2Image = $('.wrapper.div2').find('img').attr('src');
  var div3Image = $('.wrapper.div3').find('img').attr('src');
  $('.background.div1').css('background-image', 'url(' + div1Image + ')');
  $('.background.div2').css('background-image', 'url(' + div2Image + ')');
  $('.background.div3').css('background-image', 'url(' + div3Image + ')');
});
```

Or use `background` instead of `background-image`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qw6q3t4n/1/)

---

This could be a little improvment to your script:

```
$(function() {

  $('.wrapper').find('img').each(function(index){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
      $('.background').eq(index).css('background', 'url(' + src + ') no-repeat');
  });

});
```

This is independent from the number of elements.

[Demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/rw4yc733/)

Comment: Awesome and thorough answer! Thanks so much.